# PHP Display as long as field is unique

Tags: php, mysql, unique

In my MySQL table, there are several rows which share the same "case number". I want to display the case numbers on a page but do not want cases which have multiple rows to be displayed more than once. This is basically the code I am using:

```
//select all records
$query="SELECT * FROM cases ";
$rt=mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_error();                   

while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($rt)){

echo $nt['case'];
echo $nt['date_created'];

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

using [distinct](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL) like

```
SELECT distinct(case) ,date_created FROM cases
```

Answer (score 2):

you need

```
SELECT DISTINCT(case_number) FROM cases
```

you might want to use `ORDER BY` to order the `case_number` or by any other field you want.

Answer (score 2):

their is two ways you can do it.

either use `distinct` or `group by` like

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(case), 
  date_created
FROM
  cases;
```

or

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  cases
GROUP BY
  case;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array in which the current `case numbers` are present. Loop through the list every time to prevent duplicates.